# Column.Index is not reflecting immediately in TDBGrid

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I have a TDBGrid and have a Client dataset associated through a TDataSource.
When i try to re-arrange the columns of the grid programtically this works fine when there are one or more columns in the grid.

Lets say, i made all the columns visible to false. So, the grid does not have any columns yet.
Now, when i set the Index of column at 11 to 0.

```
Columns[iColIndx].Index := iNewColIndex;
// Assume iColIndx = 11 and iNewColIndex = 0

Columns[iNewColIndex].Visible := True;
//Making the column visible
```

The above assignment of column index is not getting reflected in the Grid. If i try setting it for twice or thrice, then it is getting reflected. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Did you try setting `Visible := True;` first, and then setting the `Index`? It may be that the change in order is actually deferred until the grid is actually showing (didn't look at the code, but it's the first thing I'd suspect and the first change I'd try).

Comment: I have tried the same, but no luck. The index of the column is not getting changed, but setting the visible is showing the column properly. In this case, if i show another column for which the index is less than the current showing, the order of the columns were getting changed if we see from the column index perspective. Is there any method to force the columns to change the index? I have even tried exposing the ColumnMoved method in the TDBGrid, but it is also of no use.

Comment: Did you try calling `Columns.Update` after changing the index?

Comment: ahmm...i solved it...It was my mistake in the first place.. I have assigned the OnDrawDataCell for the grid for drawing the gradients, but i m not calling the DefaultDrawDataCell from there. Moreover, the DefaultDrawing was truned off. After setting the DefaultDrawing and calling the DefaultDrawDataCell from within the DrawDataCell event handler it is working fine now....Thank u very much for the support...

Comment: But interesting thing is that, i couldn't find any reference to setting the column index or updating the field from the DeafaultDrawDataCell...but this damn thing is working now...

Comment: if you have resolved it, then you should post your answer and accept it...

Comment: It is acceptable, and even encouraged to answer (and accept) your own quesitons: blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I have assigned `OnDrawDataCell` of the grid for drawing the gradients, but I was not calling the `DefaultDrawDataCell` from there. Moreover, the `DefaultDrawing` property was turned off.

After setting `DefaultDrawing` and calling `DefaultDrawDataCell` from within the `DrawDataCell` event handler, it is working fine now.